# Eclipse Mars C++ slow-build

Tags: c++, eclipse

I've a problem with Eclipse Mars C++ ( on windows )  , it builds any project in 20 seconds ( at least ) even if it's just printing "Hello World" , so what should I do ?

Comment: Start by cutting and pasting the compiler command line into a console window to see if the problem is with Eclipse or if it is global.

Comment: It's with Eclipse only

Comment: Can't say I'm having that problem. Is it the same with Eclipse Luna?

Comment: It's the same with Eclipse Kepler , I did'n try Luna

Comment: Rats. I hate mystery weirds.

Answer (score 0):

try to re-install minGw compiler,and also make sure that u have the latest java installed